# Hiding value of a selector in a grid dynamically

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to hide these duplicate inventory ID values for the "price" and "Cost" lines (when one "adds" an item to the grid it creates three lines), but the selector description still appears.

How can I just make these value come up blank in the grid?

Even better, how can I disable a link command so if someone inadvertently clicks then it wont link to the stock item screen?

[image]

Here is my code thus far:

```
    protected void _(Events.FieldSelecting<FPPriceSheetDetail, FPPriceSheetDetail.inventoryID> e)
    {
        if (e.Row is null) return;
        if (e.Row.RowType == FPPriceSheetRowType.BreakQty) return;
        var state = PXFieldState.CreateInstance(e.ReturnState, typeof(string), true, false, 1, null, null, null, nameof(FPPriceSheetDetail.inventoryID));
        state.SelectorMode = PXSelectorMode.TextMode;
        state.DescriptionName = "";
        state.ValueField = "";
        state.Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible;
        state.Visible = true;

        e.ReturnState = state;
        e.ReturnValue = "";
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather review the pxSelector and in the condition only show 1-row type - this will remove the duplicates. The point of the selector is to select one of the values within the result - assuming all the information the selector are selectable.